# Burn ASP website to a CD

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, ado

I need to burn a copy of my asp website to a cd and it must run when a user puts the cd in the drive. The site uses an access database and asp include files and all that.

Is there a way to get the site to run off a cd without installing ASP on windows?

Thanks,
Airlok

Answer (score 1):

Server to Go
http://www.server2go-web.de/

BabyWebServer (Pablo Software)

XAMPP

or something like that would probably work.

One issue is the Access database- if you are using ACCDB and ACE 12 driver they might not have that.

Server2Go might be best.  No affiliation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need to make a flat copy of your site - ie visit all the pages and save them as html files and update all the links...  not pleasant, but you can probably find a program to help you do it.

Comment: This wont work if there is any dynamic inputs/calculations which there probably is.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Who knows if it's ASP.NET, but if this is the case, you can bundle your ASP.NET application with Cassini in that CD, but I don't know if read-only storage would be valid for this web server:</strike>

- http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/

Just give a try.

I leave the text because maybe others would find this answer useful.

Comment: Then I believe I can't help you in your problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no, not *exactly* as you described.  These are all the options I can think of:

**Link**

Host the site yourself (it is a website afterall!)  If you want it to look more like a product, create a Visual Basic or some other wrapper app that wraps the browser in an application type interface and loads your website up.  The end user will of course need an active internet connection.

**Executable**

Look at Visual Basic, it uses the same markup as ASP (VBscript) and is reasonably easy to understand so if the project is small you should be able to port it reasonably easily into an EXE file.